# Icon color not changing when focusing on input

Tags: html, css

I have been trying a couple of methods here to make my font-awesome icon colored white as I focus on my input... but nothing seems to work.

My code looks like this:

HTML

```
<div id="container">
  <form id="form">
    <input type="password" placeholder="Code" required id="input">
    <div class="icon"><i class="fas fa-user-secret"></i></div>
    <hr>
    <br>
    <center>
      <button id="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </center>
  </form>
</div>
```

I've tried doing:

```css
input:focus + .fas-fa-user-secret {
    color: #fff;
}

input:focus + .fas {
    color: #fff;
}

input:focus + .i {
    color: #fff;
}
```

But none of the above CSS code works. Not even the text in the input is white, but whenever I remove the + and the rest it does work for input.

Any help on this is appreciated, looked at every thread about making icons a different color when focusing on input.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `input:focus+.icon` since you have your icon inside the `.icon` div.

```css
input:focus+.icon {
  color: #ff0000;
}

input:focus {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<div id="container">
  <form id="form">
    <input type="password" placeholder="Code" required id="input">
    <div class="icon"><i class="fas fa-user-secret"></i></div>
    <hr>
    <br>
    <center>
      <button id="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </center>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok the icon colors now, but the input text doesnt change color..?

Comment: @ZeeStra You need to add another rule for it. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using general sibling combinator, which select its siblings right after it, which is a `<div>`, not the icon.

> ```
> input:focus + .fas-fa-user-secret {
>     color: #fff;
> }
> ```

What you may want to do is set `color: inherit` to the icon, and then set desiring color for the div via this CSS selector and it will be fine

```
input:focus + div {
    //your style
}
```